# Core Location iOS8 compatibility with iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, core-location

I have written the following code in my iOS8 compatible app. The app works fine on iOS8, and surprisingly to me, iOS7. My question is, why doesn't this code crash on iOS7?

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
.
.
CLAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
.
// TODO some of these statuses are iOS8 only not iOS7 - need to check.
if ((authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) || (authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) ||
(authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse))    {
<some actual code>
}
```

The constants kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse and kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways were introduced with iOS8 so I was expecting tragedy when I tried to run it in the iOS7 simulator but it ran just fine. Is this an issue that I should be worried about on real iOS7 devices (I don't have one any more) or is there something that says this code works on iOS7 that I don't know?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS7, `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways` and `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse` enum values are mapped to `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` (which is deprecated in iOS 8, by the way) by the iOS8 SDK. That's why you won't be getting any crash.